# Visual Studio 2013 rewriting my FontFamily binding to "Global User Interface"

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

Whenever I save my XAML page in Windows Store C# application project, the value for my `FontFamily` property for a `TextBlock` is rewritten from:

```
FontFamily="{Binding SettingsViewModel.Font}"
```

to

```
FontFamily="Global User Interface"
```

What can I do for this to stop?

Comment: It seems that Blend also likes to change code in some situations without asking :D